# php saying successful but mysql not updating

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update MySQL Database via PHP. I am getting that the Update was successful, how ever MySQL is not being updated. I tried the query in MySQL and it is working but there but not via the PHP page. Why?

```
<?php 
include("checksession.php"); 
$Id = $_POST['Id'];
$_SESSION['Id'] = $Id;

include("dbconnect.php");

$sql = "UPDATE part SET Available = 'Yes' WHERE Id = '$Id'";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $con);

if($result)
{
Header("Location: Item.php?eMsg=Made Available");
}
else
{
Header("Location: Item.php?eMsg=Unable to Make Available");
}

?>
```

Comment: You have attempted to debug the actual value of `$Id`? (which is vulnerable to SQL injection, by the way - at a _minimum_, you must call `mysql_real_escape_string()` on it)

Comment: Are you sure there are rows that match the condition `WHERE id = $id` ?

Comment: is your Id field in table is Text or Varchar..
If not then dont use '$Id'.. instead you can try this query
`"UPDATE part SET Available = 'Yes' WHERE Id = ".$Id`

Comment: isn't `is_numeric()` condition better for checking numeric values passed in Sql command?

Comment: Maybe you are trying to call it with a GET parameter after a question mark? POST must come from a form or Ajax.

Comment: Try executing the code directly at the DB to see if it actually gets to select something.

Comment: Answer below and my comment will explain. But I will additionally suggest you stop using the mysql_* commands and use mysqli_* functions/class or PDO.

Comment: Add exit() after the header() statements to avoid 'headers already sent errors

Comment: Any time spent learning the `mysql_query` interface is a waste of time. Please stop what you're doing now, fussing around with this, and spend the thirty minutes it takes to [learn PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and save yourself from a whole host of potential problems. This short example has a severely dangerous SQL injection bug that needs to be addressed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution use native function [mysql_affected_rows()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-affected-rows.php):

```
$Request = mysql_query($sql, $con);
$Result = mysql_affected_rows();
```

Comment: You should say why... i.e. $result/$request etc will only say that insert/update queries have been executed... but that using mysql_affected_rows() will tell HOW MANY rows have been updated/inserted and thus is what to test the query on.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

> $sql = "UPDATE part SET Available = 'Yes' WHERE Id = '{$Id}'";